# Data with conflicting "parent" attribute

Tags: gatsby

I am using the `gatsby-source-filesystem` and `gatsby-transformer-json` plugins to import data into GraphQL from JSON files.

The JSON files that I am consuming are produced by an external process and I have no control over the schema of the files. This is presenting a problem as the data files have a `parent` attribute which I wish to make available in GraphQL.

This is clashing with the `parent` attribute of the `Node` model. As a result the value of the `parent` attribute from the JSON file is overwritten with the UUID of the parent `Node` by Gatsby.

Is there a way to retain the original `parent` field from the JSON files without having to change the format of the JSON files? Is there some way I could map it to another field name like `_parent` (similar to what Gatsby does if there is an existing field called `id` -> `_id`)?

---

### Example Files

`data/stephen.json`:

```
name: Stephen
height: 123
```

`data/carol.json`:

```
name: Carol
height: 123
parent: Stephen
```